# Displaying the following query as a comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following query:

```
SELECT coalesce(COUNT('view_id'),0) level1count,y,m
    from
    (select 1 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 2 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 3 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 4 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 5 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 6 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 7 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 8 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 9 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 10 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 11 as m,2016 as y
    union
    select 12 as m ,2016 as y
    ) months
    left join page_views on(months.m = month(page_views.view_date) and months.y = year(page_views.view_date))
    group by months.m, year(page_views.view_date)
```

Which results in the following:

```
level1count    Year    Month
-----------------------------------------
1              2016    1
1              2016    2
1              2016    3
1              2016    4
34             2016    5
1392           2016    6
49             2016    7
1095           2016    8
1173           2016    9
859            2016    10
605            2016    11
100            2016    12
```

I need to get the level1count displayed like this:

1,1,1,1,34,1392,49,1095,1173,859,605,100

Using PHP - which I am new to and developing a site in it. I was thinking that maybe it needs to be put in an array and then echo that somehow?

Sorry if this is a dumb question but like I said - very new to PHP and slowly getting to grips with it.

Many thanks

JS

Comment: Any PHP Code so far? Basicly moving all `level1count` values into an array `$array[]=$row['level1count']` then do `implode(',',$array);`. that will do the job.

Comment: SHow the code you use to process the resultset from that query **Edit your question** dont paste in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$db_connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($db_connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "your query here";
$result = $db_connection->query($sql);
$arrLevel1 = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($arrLevel1, $row['level1count'];

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arrLevel1);
echo $comma_separated;
$conn->close();
?>
```

*Keep in mind the query is just an example to keep things simple. It's not safe and allows sql injection.

Comment: Thank you very much - that sorted it and has increased my knowledge of PHP!! Cheers JS

Comment: Glad I could help! Cheers!